# Can someone please confirm my answer for the side and area of this sub tended angle please?

Tags: trigonometry

Sorry to do this once again, but I have a quiz coming up so I must be diligent with the confirmations.

So the question is as follows: find the length s and area a. Round answers to three decimal places.

Theta= 50 degrees, radius= 9 cm

I got s= 7.854 cm and a= 35.343 cm^2

Is this correct?

Once again, thank you for the input!

Answer (score 0):

We have $S = \frac{\theta}{360} × 2πr$

$= \frac{50}{360} × 2 × π × 9$

$= \frac{5}{2} × π$

$= 7.857$ cm

Also,

$A = \frac{\theta}{360} × πr^2$

$= \frac{50}{360} × π × 81$

$= \frac{5}{4} × π × 9$

$= 35.357  \text{cm}^2$